# IoT/CoAP node discovery packet

Tags: iot, service-discovery, coap

How exactly should I discover all nodes that do something useful in my network?

Most CoAP documentation I've seen talks about protocol when connection is already established, but how to know where the endpoints are?

I found [OIC specification](https://openconnectivity.org/resources/specifications) which says that discovery packets should be sent over IPv6 to multicast `FF0X:0:0:0:0:0:0:158` ([All OCF Nodes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml)) port 5683 (UDP?). The packet should be "GET /oic/res" `senddiscovery` request. What is that `senddiscovery`?

The OIC spec also says CBOR encoding should be used for response, but doesn't describe what is the meaning of the returned data.

Comment: you mean query to `resource directory` in `CoAP`? The Get request to `.well-known/core` will do the discovery which return data as `core-link format`.

Comment: Never heard of `resource directory`. I thought all nodes are independent and I can just send some broadcast packet to discover them and then query services on each.